# ERROR 1064 near 'LEFT JOIN'

Tags: mysql, join

I create two temporary tables and join them together using the following codes but encounter `ERROR 1064 near 'LEFT JOIN'`.

```sql
(SELECT DISTINCT routes.route_short_name, MIN(stop_times.stop_sequence) AS first_stop, stops.stop_name AS first_stop_name
FROM trips
JOIN routes ON ...
JOIN stop_times ON ...
JOIN stops ON ...
JOIN calendar ON ...
GROUP BY stop_times.trip_id) first_table
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT routes.route_short_name, MAX(stop_times.stop_sequence) AS last_stop, stops.stop_name AS last_stop_name
FROM trips
JOIN routes ON ...
JOIN stop_times ON ...
JOIN stops ON ...
JOIN calendar ON ...
GROUP BY stop_times.trip_id) last_table
ON first_table.route_short_name = last_table.route_short_name;
```

The desired results are something like:

```
route_short_name, first_stop_name, last_stop_name
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you missing the actual main select statement?

```
SELECT route_short_name, first_stop_name, last_stop_name FROM   --this part is missing
(SELECT DISTINCT ...) first_table
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT ...) last_table
ON first_table.route_short_name = last_table.route_short_name;
```

Comment: Thx. It works. What is the new table name to replace `SOMETHING` as you mentioned?

Comment: @SparkandShine it's not a table name, `SOMETHING` stands for the columns that you want to select, Its up to you.

Comment: @SparkandShine you should select the columns that you want to appear in the output, according to your question it's `route_short_name, first_stop_name, last_stop_name`, see updated answer

Comment: I can only use `*` because of no new table name. Using `route_short_name` causes ambiguous error `ERROR 1052`.

Comment: @SparkandShine prefix column name with table name to resolve ambiguity. i.e. `last_table.route_short_name`, since you're joining on this column it doesn't matter which table to use